# Progress bar in bash (with fixed length)

Tags: bash, progress-bar

I'm trying to write a script that parses a file [`output.txt`], each line has a `0` or `1`, and the script will loop each entry in the file and display `#` if `1`, and `.` if `0`, which works with the below code, outputting progress as `###..##.....##.#.#.`:

```
#!/bin/bash

entries=`cat input.txt | wc -l`
currentbar=""
while read line; do
  if [[ "$line" == "1" ]];  then
    let "parse_resp++"
    reqstatus="#"
    bar="$currentbar$reqstatus"
    currentbar=$bar
    echo -ne "$bar\r"
    sleep 0.1
  else
    let "parse_resp++"
    reqstatus="."
    bar="$currentbar$reqstatus"
    currentbar=$bar
    echo -ne "$bar\r"
    sleep 0.1
  fi
done < input.txt
echo -ne "\n"
```

- I would like the length of the bar to be fixed and based on the number of lines (if the line is not parsed already, it will show a `-`), expecting to get:

  ```
  ###..##...---------
  ```
- The `\r` below does not seem to work to write on top of the current line , as it outputs: 
   (I tried changing `-` to `.` but it has the same problem)

  ```
  #-----------------#----------------#---------------.--------------.-------------#------------#-----------.----------.---------.--------.-------.------#-----#----.---#--.-#.
  ```

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  entries=`cat input.txt | wc -l`
  currentbar=""
  echo ""

  while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" == "1" ]];  then
      let "parse_resp++"
      nbleft=`echo "$entries - $parse_resp" | bc`
      dashleft=`seq -s- $nbleft|tr -d '[:digit:]'`
      reqstatus="#"
      bar="$currentbar$reqstatus$dashleft"
      currentbar=$bar
      echo -ne "$bar\r"
    else
      let "parse_resp++"
      nbleft=`echo "$entries - $parse_resp" | bc`
      dashleft=`seq -s- $nbleft|tr -d '[:digit:]'`
      reqstatus="."
      bar="$currentbar$reqstatus$dashleft"
      currentbar=$bar
      echo -ne "$bar\r"
    fi
  done < input.txt
  echo -ne "\n"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The `\r` works fine, but you're storing *the entire old bar* in `$currentbar` – including $dashleft – and you just keep appending on every iteration.

You should probably use `currentbar+=$reqstatus`.